# Java HashMap containsKey function

Tags: java, hashmap

Somebody please tell me the function `containsKey()` of `HashMa`p that how does it work internally. does it use `equals` or `hashcode` function to match the key. I am using `string` keys for a `hashmap` and when I am using the key dynamically the `containskey` returns `false`. e.g. (Just a sample code not the original one I am using in application)

```
class employee {
    employee(String name) {
       return name;
     }
}

class test {
    HashMap hm = new HashMap();
    hm.put("key1",new Employee("emp1"));
    hm.put("key2",new Employee("emp2"));
    hm.put("key3","emp4");
    hm.put("new Employee("emp5")","emp4");
    System.out.println(hm.containsKey("emp5"));
}
```

Comment: What does following code mean? hm.put("new Employee("emp5")","emp4");

Comment: Does your code compile?...

Answer (score 2):

The key is an Employee object, not a string, in containsKey you have a string. That comparison will return false, because string "emp5" is not equal to an object Employee.

Here is a quote from containsKey doc:

> Returns true if this map contains a mapping for the specified key. More formally, returns true if and only if this map contains a mapping for a key k such that (key==null ? k==null : key.equals(k))

Since in your case key is a string, 'equals' will return 'true' only if k is a string as well and its content is the same as that of key.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has many errors, this is invalid `hm.put("new Employee("emp5")","emp4");`

Also use generic types with collections

```
HashMap<String,employee> hm = new HashMap<String,employee>();
```

And name you class `Employee` not `employee` , Begin with capital for class names. Also you are calling `new Employee` Whereas you classname is `employee`.

According to the [source](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/util/HashMap-source.html) for hashMap . It calls `equals()` on the keys (in your case which would mean `equals` for `String`) internally

```
public boolean containsKey(Object key)
 {
 int idx = hash(key);
 HashEntry<K, V> e = buckets[idx];
  while (e != null)
   {
    if (equals(key, e.key))
    return true;
    e = e.next;
   }
   return false;
 }
```

Your valid code (assuming you are not trying to achieve something unusual) should look like this :-

```
class Employee {
    String name;

    Employee(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

class Test {
    public void hello() {
        HashMap<String,Employee> hm = new HashMap<String,Employee>();
        hm.put("key1", new Employee("emp1"));
        hm.put("key2", new Employee("emp2"));
        hm.put("key3", new Employee("emp4"));
        hm.put("key4", new Employee("emp5"));
        System.out.println(hm.containsKey("key4")); 
     }
}
```

Comment: You're aware of the fact that the `hm.put`'s and the `System.out.println` method calls are not within a method, and therefore your 'valid' code won't compile?

Comment: As I already said this is just sample code. Just a pseudo kind to make my doubt clear to you all. Definitely I can not compile this code and my real application is also different from this code.

Answer (score 0):

Corrected Code:

```
HashMap hm= new HashMap();
hm.put("key1",new Employee("emp1"));
hm.put("key2",new Employee("emp2"));
hm.put("key3","emp4");

System.out.println(hm.containsKey("key1"));
```

This will return `true`.

You are saving Employee object against String keys. So you need to check the valid key. In your case `emp5` is not used as a key while adding elements to hashmap.

For your second question:
It internally checks hashcode of the key first. If hashcodes are same it will check equals method.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming

```
employee(String name) {
       return name;
     }
```

Is not a `constructor` and it is some method this piece of code will not compile. As you are returning `String` but you dint specify the return type in the method.

Moreover this line  `hm.put("new Employee("emp5")","emp4");`
you have specified the key as

`new Employee("emp5")` and you are searching using the key `emp5` in the containsKey() obviously it will return false because

`containsKey() -Returns true if this map contains a mapping for the specified key.`

Comment: I didn't down vote you but as a rule of thumb spell check an answer before you post or quickly edit.

Comment: what you are trying to say?

Comment: I really dont understand how can people down vote without pointing the specific reason

Comment: It would be nice if people explained there criticisms. They lose rep when they down vote so I guess that's the systems way of balancing.

Comment: Your first answer was not an answer at all. It was a comment, saying: "Your code does not compile." That's still part of your answer, even though it doesn't matter. The question is about a `HashMap` and the `containsKey()` method, not about why code doesn't compile (OP even included a note saying this is not the original code). Add that as a side note in your answer, not as the first and foremost part of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Internally, a hash map can be implemented with an array of linked lists.

The key is passed to a routine (the hash) which gives back a number.  The number is then divided by the size of the array, giving a remainder.  That remainder is the linked list you then travel to see if any of the nodes exactly matches the key.

The advantages are that if you have a properly balanced hash function, and (let's say) an array of 32 items, you can quickly discard the searching of 31/32 (or +90%) of your possible values in a constant time operation.

Other means of implementation exist; however, they are computationally similar.

An example of a (very bad) hash algorithm for Strings might be to simply add up all the ASCII character values.  Very good hash algorithms tend to give back an evenly distributed number based on the expected inputs, where incremental inputs do not incrementally fill adjacent buckets.

So, to find out if a hash map contains a key, get the result of the hash function on the key, and then walk down the correct linked list checking each entry for the key's presence.

In C, a "node" in the linked list.

```
struct Node {
  char* key;
  char* value;
  struct Node* next;
};
```

In C, the "hashmap"

```
struct HashMap {
  int size;
  struct Node* listRoots;
};
```

The algorithm

```
int containsKey(HashMap* hashMap, char* key) {
  int hash = hashFunc(key);
  Node* head = hashMap->listRoots[hash % hashMap->size];
  while (head != 0) {
    if (strcmp(head->key, key)) {
      return TRUE;
    }
  }
  return FALSE;
}
```

Keep in mind my C is a bit rusty, but hopefully, you'll get the idea.